# The FileStream couldn't find the file

Tags: c#, maui

I'm working on a school project, creating an app using .NET MAUI. I'm attempting to read a JSON file from the raw folder of the MUAI, modify a value, and then update the JSON file with the new value.

The part that reads the JSON is working, but when I try to modify the JSON, it says that it was not possible to find the archive.

This is the code:

```
            string jsonArchiveName = "test.json";

            // Read the json 
            using Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(jsonArchiveName);
            using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // modfy the json
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            obj.objeto.value = num;
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

            // and finaly write on the json
            using FileStream fileStreamWrite = new FileStream(jsonArchiveName, FileMode.Truncate);
            byte[] messageByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output);
            fileStreamWrite.Write(messageByte, 0, messageByte.Length);
```

I'm encountering an issue on the
`using FileStream fileStreamWrite = new FileStream(jsonArchiveName, FileMode.Truncate);`
It throw me an error.
Error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\teste2.json'.'

I don't know why it's not looking on the same path like
`using Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(jsonArchiveName);`

Comment: you can't write to files in the app bundle.  You will need to copy the file to a user writable path.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify an app's bundled file. But you can copy a bundled file to the cache directory or app data directory. The following example uses OpenAppPackageFileAsync to copy a bundled file to the app data folder:

```
public async Task CopyFileToAppDataDirectory(string filename)
{
    // Open the source file
    using Stream inputStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filename);

    // Create an output filename
    string targetFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, filename);

    // Copy the file to the AppDataDirectory
    using FileStream outputStream = File.Create(targetFile);
    await inputStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}
```